# Could not load type Confluent.Kafka.Serialization.StringDeserializer

Tags: .net-core, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

[image]

Hello all, I am Getting this error in the Intialize() method for Kafka consumrer.

Comment: Could you show what you are doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`Utf8Deserializer`](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/src/Confluent.Kafka/Deserializers.cs#L33), no StringDeserializer.

Try to use class names in the properties, not raw strings.